# Would Dual Booting Ubuntu with Windows effect Android Studio Emulator?

Tags: dual-boot, kvm-virtualization, android-studio, android-emulator

My Development machine is dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.10.

I'm trying to use Flutter on Ubuntu 18.10 and everything seems to be working fine except for Android Studio AVD (Android Virtual Device.) Whenever I run the device it throws a very weird error about the emulator. I've scoured for a solutions and no useful fixes have turned up.

I decided to try and install and run Flutter on the Windows side (mostly to see if it was a hardware thing or if something was going on with Ubuntu.) It again kept throwing strange errors about the emulator until I figured out that Hyper-V was interfering with HAXM. Once I disabled Hyper-V, everything worked perfectly.

The main question I have is: Does dual booting Ubuntu somehow block AVD from accessing KVM in Ubuntu? It seems it does since I saw one VM interfere with HAXM and could draw the conclusion that there is a similar process interfering with KVM.

If it does is there a work around?

Any input would be greatly appreciated since I'm kinda lost as to what's going on.

### UPDATE:

Here are the two errors AVD throws before it crashes:

```
Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.abm [bit 5]
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Comment: The specific error about the emulator would be useful to know about, since you haven't shared it we can't really give any assitance here.  Typically however dual booting would *not* affect Android Studio or its emulator.

Comment: Agreed. Dual booting alone doesn't have any effect at all on the Android emulator. But something you haven't told us about might. Try including more details about your situation, such as specific error messages, configuration changes you have made, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. I added the two error codes thrown.

Comment: That's a strange one. Has the Android emulator ever run _with acceleration enabled_ under Ubuntu on this PC? What processor does this PC have?